# How can i remove a li before jquery Mobile render the page

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a mobile site: http://m.gbin1.com

and i need to remove one of the navigation item like "home" by jquery because now it has 7 navigation items , and look bad, but i cannot use jquery to implement it.  for example, use .remove to delete one of items.

any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to manipulate the DOM before jQuery Mobile is initialized, you must do it in the `pagebeforeload` event. See the [events documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/events.html) for more information. Simply placing your .remove() code in a standard dom-ready function will only fire once for the initial page load.

```
$(document).bind('pagebeforeload', function(event, data) {
    $('nav ul li:first').remove();
});
```

Comment: it looks even if you add remove() in this function, still will show navigation item when pageinit was called.

Comment: Are you sure it's being called before jquery mobile is initalized? The code must be defined _before_ the jquery mobile script is included on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I found pagebeforecreate is right choice, now http://m.gbin1.com can handle add/remove

well.

```
        $(document).bind('pagebeforecreate', function(event, data) {
            $('nav ul').append('<li><a href="javascript:void(0)">new gbin1.com item</a></li>');
        });
```